# The Using variable is not supported in the script function or filter

Tags: powershell

I am running into a little issue, I have generated runbooks using powershell.
One of them connects to Vmware using a build up similar to this

## The code

```
TempFunction{
connects to vmware using VMuser1 credentials
runs code etc...
All is well
return $TempVariable
}
$TempVariable = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock ${function:TempFunction} -ComputerName localhost
```

This all works fine.

---

The problem is that when I introduce a global array named InfoArray that stores information along the way and at the end wish to write it to a different server using other credentials it fails stating "Invoke-Command: The Using variable is not supported in the script function or filter"

Here is my introduced code:

```
#Append gathered log information to log
    $strScriptUser = "domain\FileUser"
    $strPass = "Password01"
    $PSS = ConvertTo-SecureString $strPass -AsPlainText -Force
    $cred = new-object system.management.automation.PSCredential $strScriptUser, $PSS
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Add-Content $using:Logfile $using:InfoArray } -Credential $cred
return $TempVariable
}
```

Any ideas as to how I could solve this issue?
The following does not work

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Add-Content $Logfile $InfoArray } -Credential $cred
```

Regards
Akr

Answer (score 1):

Pass them as arguments to this script block, since it doesn't support using.

### Sample

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    param($logfile,$infoArray) 
    Add-Content $Logfile $InfoArray 
} -Credential $cred -ArgumentList @($logfile,$infoArray)
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I can confirm however that it does not trigger. When the sample you sent me is placed outside of a function it works, but when it is placed within a function, it fails.

Comment: By adding | wait-job | receive-job I receive the following error: "[localhost] An error occurred while starting the background process. Error reported: Access is denied." The user used to initiate the start-job -scriptblock has access to the file share where the add-content is performed.

Comment: It looks like this answered the question and now you have a new question?  I would suggest marking this one as answered and asking a new question about why accessing the file share in the job is not working (which implies we have successfully passed the parameter)

Additionally, I don't have enough of the script posted in this question to answer the next question at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to Invoke without using -computername localhost, which resulted in it working via a PS script.

The challenge was that I cannot load PowerCLi pssnapin as a 64 bit directly in system center orchestrator, and must invoke for it to work.

Finally, what seemed to work was running the function using the server name rather than localhost.

```
$TempVariable = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock ${function:TempFunction} -computerName *ServerName*
```